# How to target this component in client script?

Tags: astrojs

I have a component that may be displayed twice on page. When the page gets loaded, I want to execute a script that either shows or hides some elements of my component. The code I currently have is as follows:

```html
<script>
    revealCurrentArticle();

    function revealCurrentArticle() {
        const path = window.location.pathname;
        const currentLi = document.querySelector(`[data-path="${path}"]`);

        if (currentLi === null) {
            return;
        }

        let parent: HTMLElement | null | undefined = currentLi.parentElement;
        while(parent) {
            if (parent.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "ul") {
                break;
            }
            
            parent.classList.remove('hidden');
            parent = parent.parentElement?.parentElement;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The issue is with the line:

```js
const currentLi = document.querySelector(`[data-path="${path}"]`);
```

It finds the element, but not necessarily the one that belongs to this instance of the component.

I know that I could use `document.querySelectorAll`, but that makes my component aware of the fact that it might be displayed multiple times on the page, and I don't want that. Is there any way to make sure that `currentLi` always contains a reference to HTML element within this component instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a unique value for each usage of the component in the component script. Then, pass it to the client-side script using [`define:vars`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#definevars) and use it as both a class & in the selector.

As an example:

```
---
const id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 11)
---

<div class={id}></div>

<script define:vars={{id}}>
  console.log(document.querySelector(`.${id}`))
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use `id` as an ID and not a class it must not start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

### Path limitations

The path is intended to be the same for the page that can contain multiple components of the same instance.

### Using define:vars

it is possible to use define:vars but it results in duplicating the script for every instance as it turns the vars into const.

The following suggested solution can be based on js alone and can result in a single script for all components instances

### Using url search params

A common way for "deep linking" which is referencing different items within the same page is to use the query search parameters which can reference the id of the element you want to deep link.

Example `path/?modal=image1`

Your example is a little bit abstract, to make it easier to understand let's think of a page that has multiple images, each one has a component that can open a modal.

### Example

this is a snippet from an astro component

```html
---
const assetname = ... unique instance name
---
<div class="container panzoom" data-name={assetname} >
      <img src={asseturl} />
  <PanZoomModal url={asseturl} />
</div>
```

this is an example function that checks the url search params and gets the specific param in this case called modal like in `path/?modal=image1`

in this case an event is sent to trigger opening the corresponding modal that is already targetting the unique instance with the right `data-name` attribute

```js
  const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
  const modal_name = params.get('modal');
  if(modal_name){
    const container = document.querySelector(`.container.panzoom[data-name="${modal_name}"]`)
    if(container){
    event(container,"init")
    }
  }
```

### reference example

A complete example of this behavior can be found here

- checking the url params https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-big-doc/blob/09391234d1ab1a72930f9059448a6d72520191b1/src/components/panzoom.js#L26
- the unique data attribute https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-big-doc/blob/09391234d1ab1a72930f9059448a6d72520191b1/src/components/panzoom.astro#L23